# Seleccionar un input type select y habilitar otro input con información en php, javascript mysqli

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli

tengo el siguiente formulario en HTML:

```
<form action="agregar.php" method="POST">
<br>            
<table>
<tr>
<?php
   $sql5 = "SELECT id_flota,nom_flota FROM para_flota";
   $result5=mysqli_query($conn,$sql5);
?>      
    <td>Flota:</td> 
    <td>
    <select id="flota_pro" name="flota_pro" required >
    <option></option> 
    <?php

    while ($row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5))
    {
    ?>  
        <option value="<?=$row5['nom_flota']?>"><?=$row5['nom_flota']?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php
   $sql6 = "SELECT id_equipo,nro_equipo FROM para_equipo";
   $result6=mysqli_query($conn,$sql6);
?>
<td>Equipo:</td>
<td>
<select id="equipo_pro" name="equipo_pro" required >
    <option></option> 
    <?php

    while ($row6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result6))
    {
    ?>  
        <option value="<?=$row6['nro_equipo']?>"><?=$row6['nro_equipo']?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="GUARDAR">   
</form>
```

Y ya como ven relleno las opciones con una consulta a la base de datos, como puedo hacer con javascript o php para que al seleccionar el campo flota me traiga solo los equipos que pertenecen a esa flota en el segundo select que se llama equipos.

tengo dos tablas en la base de datos:

La que me trae las flotas se llama: para_flota esa tabla tiene solo dos campos (id_flota,nom_flota)

Y la segunda tabla se llama: para_equipo esta tabla tiene (id_equipo,nro_equipo,flota)

En la segunda tabla estoy guardando el nro del equipo y la flota a la que pertenece ese equipo.

Entonces lo que estoy buscando hacer es que al seleccionar la flota en el formulario, me habilite el segundo select los equipos que pertenecen a esa flota.

De que manera lo podría hacer? cualquier ayuda me seria de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución en Ajax y jQuery está muy bien porque evitas recargar la página. Aunque, si este detalle no te importa, igual te resulta más sencillo profundizar un poco más en PHP que aprender tres tecnologías nuevas.

La solución en PHP sería algo así:

```
<form method="POST">
<br>            
<table>
<tr>
    <?php
       $sql5 = "SELECT id_flota,nom_flota FROM para_flota";
       $result5=mysqli_query($conn,$sql5);
    ?>      
    <td>Flota:</td> 
    <td>
    <select id="flota_pro" name="flota_pro" required >
    <option></option> 
    <?php
    while ($row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5))
    {
    ?>  
        <option value="<?=$row5['id_flota']?>"
            <?php
                if(isset(
                    $_POST['flota_pro']) 
                    and $_POST['flota_pro']==$row5['id_flota']
                ) echo ' selected ';
            ?>
        ><?=$row5['nom_flota']?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['flota_pro']))
    {
    ?>
        <tr>
        <?php
           $sql6 = "
                SELECT id_equipo,nro_equipo
                  FROM para_equipo
                  WHERE flota=".($_POST['flota_pro']*1).";
            ";
           $result6=mysqli_query($conn,$sql6);
        ?>
        <td>Equipo:</td>
        <td>
        <select id="equipo_pro" name="equipo_pro" required >
            <option></option> 
            <?php

            while ($row6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result6))
            {
            ?>  
                <option value="<?=$row6['nro_equipo']?>"
                    <?php
                        if(isset(
                            $_POST['equipo_pro']) 
                            and $_POST['equipo_pro']==$row6['nro_equipo']
                        ) echo ' selected ';
                    ?>              
                ><?=$row6['nro_equipo']?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>      
</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="GUARDAR">   
</form>
```

Ves que es prácticamente lo que tenías, pero enviando el formulario al mismo fichero en el que estás trabajando y haciendo uso de la superglobal `$_POST`.

Aporto dataset para realizar las pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE para_flota(
  id_flota int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nom_flota varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE para_equipo(
  id_equipo int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nro_equipo varchar(31),
  flota int,
  FOREIGN KEY(flota) REFERENCES para_flota(id_flota)
  );
INSERT INTO para_flota (nom_flota) VALUES
  ('Flota1'),('Flota2');
INSERT INTO para_equipo (nro_equipo,flota) VALUES
  ('Equipo1',1),('Equipo2',2);
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios y será un placer ampliar la respuesta

Comment: Hola David JP tu respuesta es la que más se adapta a lo que estaba buscando muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo primero aprender las bases de **Ajax** y **JQuery** para poder desarrollar algo como eso.

- Ya que **JQuery** te sirve para realizar la animación que quieres.
- Y **Ajax** para que extraiga la información de tu archivo **.php** y rellene tu input.

ejemplo:

1. Haciendo con tu la imagen que plasmaste. Quedaría de la siguiente manera.
2. Primero un archivo **index.php** el cual lleva todo tu formulario que dejaste en la imagen anterior.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>proyecto</title>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#equipo_pro').hide();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="agregar.php" method="POST">
<br>  

<table>
    <tr>
        <?php
        $sql5 = "SELECT id_flota,nom_flota FROM para_flota";
        $result5=mysqli_query($conn,$sql5);
        ?>      
            <td>Flota:</td> 
            <td>
            <select id="flota_pro" name="flota_pro" required >
            <option></option> 
            <?php

            while ($row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5))
            {
            ?>  
                <option value="<?=$row5['nom_flota']?>"><?=$row5['nom_flota']?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <select id="equipo_pro" name="equipo_pro" required>

        </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <script src="consulta_ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

3. crea un archivo JavaScript (**consulta_ajax.js**), el cual sera el puente entre el archivo **index.php** hacial el archivo **consulta_php.php** quedando de la siguiente manera.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //LLamado al jquery

    $("#flota_pro").change(function(){ //Aqui preguntamos que encuanto detecte un cambio en tu primer select entre a esta consulta
        var flota = $('#flota_pro').val(); //extraemos l valor de tu primer select

            $.ajaxSetup({ //token del ajax
            headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost/proyecto/consulta_php.php', //Aqui va tu ruta php
                data: {
                    'flota': flota, //Aqui tus variables javascript que asignaste arriba
                },
                success:function(result){
                        $('#equipo_pro').show(); //desoculta el segundo select
                        $('#equipo_pro').html(result); //Rellena el segundo select con las opciones extraidas del archivo PHP
                },error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    if(xhr.status==404) {
                        alert(thrownError); //Mensaje de erro
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

4. Creamos el archivo PHP (**consulta_php.php**), este archivo creara tu lista de opciones y los retornara hacia tu archivo **consulta_ajax.js**.

```
<?php
   $sql6 = "SELECT id_equipo,nro_equipo FROM para_equipo";
   $result6=mysqli_query($conn,$sql6);

   $list = "";

   while ($row6 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result6))
    {
        $list .= '<option value="'.$row6['nro_equipo'].'">'.$row6["nro_equipo"].'</option>';
    }
    return $list
?>
```

**Nose como este tu conexión PHP pero así es como quedaría si utilizas Ajax y JQuery**

Comment: Tu respuesta también me funciono, muchas gracias por tu aporte. muy agradecido.

Answer (score 1):

La solución que te propongo a continuación requiere de tener una noción de como manejar peticiones **AJAX** para cargar la información dinámicamente sin tener que recargar toda la página entera, si ya manejas eso no tendrás problema para leer el código.

1. Así que tu `formulario` quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<html>
<form action="agregar.php" method="POST">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <?php
            $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "DB");
            $sql5 = "SELECT id_flota,nom_flota FROM para_flota";
            $result5 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql5);
            ?>
            <td>Flota:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="flota_pro" name="flota_pro" required>
                    <option value="0" disabled>Elegir...</option>
                    <?php while ($row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5)) { ?>
                        <option value="<?= $row5['id_flota'] ?>"><?= $row5['nom_flota'] ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Equipo:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="equipo_pro" name="equipo_pro" disabled required>
                    <option></option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="GUARDAR">
</form>
</html>
```

2. Luego recomendaría crear un archivo `JS` independiente para organizar un poco mejor el código, de cualquier forma puedes incluir el script junto a tu formulario, el cuál sería:

```
<script>
    $("#flota_pro").on("change", function() {
        var idFlota = document.getElementById("flota_pro").value
        console.log(idFlota)
        $("#equipo_pro").removeAttr("disabled")
        //Consultar
        $.ajax({
            url: "consulta.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                id: idFlota
            },
        }).done(function(respuesta) {
            respuesta = jQuery.parseJSON(respuesta);
            console.log(respuesta);
            $("#equipo_pro")
                .empty()
                .removeAttr("disabled")
                .append(
                    '<option disabled selected value="0">Seleccionar...</option>'
                );
            $.each(respuesta, function(index, val) {
                $("#equipo_pro").append(
                    '<option value="' + val["id"] + '">' + val["nro"] + '</option>'
                );
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

4. Finalmente creamos un archivo `PHP` llamado "consulta" o como gustes (deberás poner la ruta del archivo en el **URL** del AJAX) que nos hará la función de consultar la BD para arrojarnos la información filtrada según nuestro **select**, cuyo código sería:

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "root", "db");
$result5 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql5);

if(isset($_POST["id"])){
    $sql6 = "SELECT id_equipo,nro_equipo FROM para_equipo WHERE id_flota = " . $_POST['id'];
    $result6 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql6);
    $i = 0;

    while ($row5 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result6)) { 
        $regresar[$i++] = array("id" => $row5['id_equipo'], "nro" => $row5['nro_equipo']);
    }
    echo json_encode($regresar);
}
?>
```

Nota que realizarlo de esta forma, aunque el código esta un poco desordenado todavía, hará ver tu formulario más dinámico porque en el **script** que creamos y mediante la función **AJAX** cada vez que cambie el usuario el primer **select** en automático va a refrescar la información del segundo.

Comment: Hola Alan tu respuesta me funciono, muchas gracias por tu tiempo y por tu aporte.

Comment: Me alegra haber leído eso. Para eso estamos, sigue preguntando qué solo así se aprende. Saludos.